# How to switch off Joomla span classes

Tags: php, css, joomla, media-queries

Hi I am looking to find out how i can change how some of my modules are shown on a mobile.

Currently I have the following in my index.php file:

```
<div id="leftcol" class="span8"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="welcome" style="xhtml" /></div>
<div id="rightcol" class="span4"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="laptop" style="xhtml" /></div>
```

which shows the 2 side by side but what I would like is to have these on top of each other when viewing on a mobile screen i.e.:

```
<div id="leftcol" class="span12"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="welcome" style="xhtml" /></div>
<div id="rightcol" class="span12"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="laptop" style="xhtml" /></div>
```

but i am not sure how i go about implementing this. Would really appreciate some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach is probably to [add some custom CSS](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/3877/120) with a media query like this or similar:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #leftcol.span8 {float: none; width: 100%;}
  #rightcol.span4 {float: none; width: 100%;}
}
```

Custom CSS files are preferred over editing the HTML or PHP code because your changes are less likely to be overwritten by future updates.